# Cannot put CI_COMMIT_SHA into variable

Tags: gitlab, gitlab-ci.yml

why does the first echo print nothing, while the second one prints the commit hash?
Syntax should be correct, as it works for pipeline id, branch name etc.

```
init:
  stage: Init
  variables:
    TEST1: '${CI_COMMIT_SHA:0:8}'
  script:
    - echo "${TEST1}"
    - echo "${CI_COMMIT_SHA:0:8}"
```

Output:

```
echo "${TEST1}"
echo "${CI_COMMIT_SHA:0:8}"
egk356ks
```

Answer (score 0):

The kind of expression you are looking at can only work where a shell is available like "before_script" or "script" sections

```
init:
  stage: Init
  before_script:
    - TEST1="${CI_COMMIT_SHA:0:8}"
  script:
    - echo "${TEST1}"
    - echo "${CI_COMMIT_SHA:0:8}"
```

Output

```
$ TEST1="${CI_COMMIT_SHA:0:8}"
$ echo "${TEST1}"
2d0d7721
$ echo "${CI_COMMIT_SHA:0:8}"
2d0d7721
```